# How does the prop `store` work in react-redux Provider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-media-library-with-react-redux-and-redux-saga-part-2), the author exports the below code and passes the entire called function, which returns an object, to the `store` prop in `Provider`. How does the `runSaga` part get ran? I don't see this in the docs.

```
const configureStore = () => {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware(); 
  return {
    ...createStore(rootReducer,
      applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)),
    runSaga: sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's missing from the tutorial.

Look at the example at the [official page of `redux-saga`](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/tree/master/docs/api#example).

The example explicitly calls the function `runSaga`

Comment: yeah it's never called in the tutorial but it still works, weird.